# Asterisk support for rfc 3327 & rfc 6140

Tags: asterisk

Does asterisk support rfc 3327 and rfc 6140 if so which version of asterisk supports these rfc's. Is there any open source sip server registrar that supports the above mentioned rfc's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Kamailio open source SIP server.

Kamailio SIP server can act as

- Registrar server
- Location server
- Proxy server
- SIP Application server
- Redirect server